# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' eval()'d code on line 1

Tags: php, syntax-error, eval, parse-error

I have trouble with PHP's `eval` function

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `*` in line,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $dane = wszystkie_monety('27');
    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM kursy_kruszywa", ARRAY_N);
    $zloto = $mylink[0][1];
    $dolar = $mylink[2][1];
    $data = $mylink[3][1];
    $dokladnosc = 2;
?>

<?php
    $start = 0;
    if($dane[$start] != null) {
        $operacja = str_replace(',', '.', $dane[$start+2]);
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 334px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            <a title="" target="" style="" rel="" href="<?php echo $dane[$start+1]; ?>" class="animacja"><img width="250" title="20_dolarow" style="" src="<?php echo $dane[$start+1]; ?>" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-59" alt=""></a>
        </td>
        <td id="nazwa">
            <?php echo $dane[$start]; ?>
        </td>
        <td id="kwota">
            <?php 
                $expression = "$dolar*$zloto/$operacja";
                eval('$wynik = '.$expression.';');                               
                echo ceil($wynik/$dokladnosc)*$dokladnosc.',00 zł';
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ; does the variables $dolar, $zloto and ôperacja exist at this point?

Comment: These are the variables to which should be recorded data on prices of the dollar and Polish zloty charged from a foreign website.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?php get_header(); 
$dane = wszystkie_monety('27'); 

$mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM kursy_kruszywa", ARRAY_N);

$zloto = $mylink[0][1];
$dolar = $mylink[2][1];
$data = $mylink[3][1];

$dokladnosc = 2;
?>

Comment: Debugging: before calling your eval, try to `var_dump` these variables and show us the result.

Comment: Why are you building that expression and a string and evaling it in the first place?

Comment: There's no error checking on `$mylink`, so if the query fails, the values will not be set. check this with `if(count($mylink) === 0) { echo 'Handle error here'; }`

Comment: Escape the dollar sign `\$` in your expression.

Comment: var_dump($zloto); - string(7) "1323.90" ----------
var_dump($dolar); -  string(0) "" ----------
var_dump($operacja); - string(19) "31.1*33.43*0.9*1.01" -----------

Comment: @Karlo Kokkak - I escape the dollar sign \$ in my expression - the error has disappeared but the price conversion does not work

Comment: @Quentin I did not build this expression, there was a code on the page after the previous programmer, and now it has stopped working.

Comment: @SergioMan — The first step to fixing it should be removing `eval`

Comment: That's also for the $ in eval()

Comment: @Quentin - ok, I removed, what's next?

Comment: Have a try with something like: `$wynik  = float($dolar)*floatval($zloto)/floatval($operacja);  
echo ceil($wynik/$dokladnosc)*$dokladnosc.',00 zł';`